# Why can't you pass just an `app_name` keyword arg when including another URLconf?

Tags: django

In the standard `urls.py` of a Django app, if I pass an `app_name` without a `namespace` into an `include()` call, like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^', include('foo.urls', app_name='foo')),
    # ...
]
```

I get a error like below when hitting one of the included urls.

`ValueError: Must specify a namespace if specifying app_name.`

So it's necessary to do:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^', include('foo.urls', namespace='foo-urls', app_name='foo')),
    # ...
]
```

I don't see the hard dependency between the two; why is it necessary to specify a `namespace` in order to be able to specify an `app_name`?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like django official doc has all the answers:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: See [#17716](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17716). Also note that the `app_name` parameter is deprecated. In 1.9+ you should set an `app_name` attribute inside `foo.urls`, which doesn't require you to set the `namespace` parameter as well. The error you're seeing is mostly an artifact of how it used to work, and there's no real reason to change it when it is deprecated anyway.

Comment: @knbk that makes sense, I should have mentioned I'm using Django 1.8(.12) @shang-wang I don't see an explicit explanation of why. The reason for wanting to use just `app_name` is that I have a third-party library that I suspect is breaking by giving it a `namespace` (it doesn't have one by default), so it would be useful to attach an `app_name` to its urls, which would make filtering `ResolverMatch` objects that come from that library much easier. Though from reading the documentation again, my understanding is `app_name` is like a "default namespace" so it might not achieve what I want anyway

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the **namespace** attribute in the **include** function, you must define **app_name** in the application **urls.py** file you are using. > [Django 2.0 URL dispatcher documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)
For instance, if this is your project structure:

```
project/
├── app1
│   └── urls.py
├── app2
│   └── urls.py
└── project
    └── urls.py
```

And you want to **include** (app1, app2) urls, you first must define **app_name** in app1/urls.py and app2/urls.py:

`file: app1/urls.py`:

```
app_name='app1'
urlpatterns = [  
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

`file: app2/urls.py`:

```
app_name='app2'
urlpatterns = [  
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

`file: project/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [  
    path('', include('app1.urls', namespace='app1')),
    path('', include('app2.urls', namespace='app2')),
]
```

So, you can now use something like this `{% url 'app1:home' %}` or `{% url 'app2:home' %}` in your template file.

Answer (score 0):

you need put: app_name in "foo.urls"

link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs